# How to solve this type of integrals?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have specific problem for solving this type of integral :

$$\int \frac{x-y}{x^2-2y^2}\, dx $$

I tried applying partial fractions, making the denominator complete square but the sum keeps on getting lengthy. Any hints Appreciated to make it simpler.

Comment: Is this a double integral? Or what is the integration variable? Are there any bounds?

Comment: Is $y$ or $x$ constant?

Comment: Yeah, this bold **dx** looks suspicious... Is it just $dx$ and you are interested in anti-derivative wrt  $x$ where $y$ is a parameter?

Comment: @Joel i hope y is some function of x

Answer (score 3):

Try this
$$
\frac{x-y}{x^2-2y^2}=\frac{x-\sqrt{2}y+\sqrt{2}y-y}{(x-\sqrt{2}y)(x+\sqrt{2}y)}=
\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{2}y}+\frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)y}{(x-\sqrt{2}y)(x+\sqrt{2}y)}=\\
=\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{2}y}+\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{2}y}-\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{2}y}\right).
$$

Answer (score 2):

By setting $x= y z $ we have:
$$ I = \int \frac{x-y}{x^2-2y^2}\,dx = y \int\frac{y z-y}{y^2 z^2 - 2 y^2}\,dz= \int \frac{z-1}{z^2-2}\,dz$$
and the last integral may be computed through partial fraction decomposition:
$$ \frac{z-1}{z^2-2} = \frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{z-\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{z+\sqrt{2}} $$
leads to:
$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\log(2-z^2)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}+z}{\sqrt{2}-z}\right).$$